# React Native-Error after declining enable location popup

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile, weather

So i am trying to make a weather app and when i decline(press NO) in the popup window for enabling location, it gives me the following error: `[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Location request failed due to unsatisfied device settings.]`

The important part of the code looks like this.

```
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: 'Permission to access location was denied, please activate location and reopen the app.',
      });

    }

    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({enableHighAccuracy:true});
    let lat = location.coords.latitude;
    let lon = location.coords.longitude;
```

Note: I am using the last version of react native, i am on android, i used expo-location for this and it works perfectly when i enable(press YES) location.

Comment: what library you are using to ask for location permission, also are you sure about the returned object will contain "status" flag.

Comment: I am using these two for the location permission:`import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';`
I am not sure about the returned object.

Comment: can you please follow this snack and report if it works for you
https://snack.expo.io/@charliecruzan/expo-map-and-location-example

Comment: When i run the snack on my phone or on the site's simulator the following error occurs: `Device: (921:881) undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo.Constants.statusBarHeight')
  Evaluating module://App.js.js
  Loading module://App.js`

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your await calls with a try catch block to catch an error.

```
try {
  let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
} catch(err) {
  //handle err
}
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work, it shows me this error `[Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: status]`
My code: https://imgur.com/BVkS86m

Comment: If you do this you can access the status variable only in the try block. If you want to use it outside you have to declare your let outside and just sign the value in the try block.